# Google App Engine NDB: need to fetch() after query?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

To retrieve entities in Google App Engine's NDB, do I need to `fetch()` after `query()`? For example:

```
account = self.request.get('account')
member = Member.query(Member.account==account).fetch()
if member:   
    # Account exists
else:        
    # Account does not exist
```

I have two questions:

1. If `.fetch()` is used, the code runs correctly. However, if
   `.fetch()` is not used, the test is always true, which means some
   entities are retrieved. What is the problem?
2. In general, do I need to use `.fetch()` if I want to retrieve
   **all** entities after a query?

Comment: As a side note, the fastest way I know of to achieve this condition (if you don't need to entity) is `if Member.query(...).get(keys_only=True):`

Answer (score 6):

If `fetch()` is not used then `member = Member.query(..)` assigns a Query class instance to `member`. So your if condition is true.

Comment: Thanks Peter, do you have an answer to question 2?

Comment: Yes, you need to use .fetch() to retrieve all entities. Just use query without any filters.

Comment: Actually `fetch()` executes the query and returns results. It does not return _all_ entities, just those defined in query parameters.

Comment: What I meant was: do I need to use `fetch()` to retrieve the entities that satisfy the query? That is, `members = Member.query(Member.age>20)` or `members = Member.query(Member.age>20).fetch()`? Because **sometimes** the results provided by the former are suitable for later processing, but **sometimes** they are not. What is the difference between them?

Comment: @Tang what you are describing is the difference between using `Member.query()` as an iterator (`for ent in query` which will retrieve results in batches and iterate smoothly, or `for ent in query.fetch()` which will retrieve all results 'up front' and iterate through a list of entities.)

Answer (score 4):

```
member_query = Member.query(Member.account==account)
```

member_query now contains a Query instance.

From there, you have a few options, but it seems that you would want to only grab ONE entity from this query. To do that, you'd say.

```
member = Member.query(Member.account==account).get()
```

Now, member is either None if the account doesn't exist, or will contain a Member model instance.

If you use .fetch(), you can specify the number of entities you want to retrieve as the first argument, or use None (or no arguments) to grab all. If there are a lot of entities that match this condition, this could be time consuming.

Another paradigm would be to iterate over the query and break or return on the first entity that matches your conditions. This paradigm would allow you to do on-the-fly conditionals not covered by your query parameters. For example...

```
for member in member_query:
    if member.active:
        return member

# No account
return None
```

Querying over this sort of membership model is less than ideal, however, because it will require a query to run every time. Of course, if you want a 'user' to have access to multiple 'profiles' (like Facebook User <-> Facebook Pages, as an example), you need something like this.

It's far more efficient to structure the list of "Profiles" that an account has access to, like so:

```
class UserAccount(ndb.Model):
    """User Account"""

    """List of keys which reference profiles this user can access"""
    profiles = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)

    def fetch_profiles(self):
        """Returns a list of profile entities this user can access"""
        return ndb.get_multi(profiles)

    def can_user_access_profile(self, profile):
        """Returns True if user can access 'profile' (either a ndb.Model or ndb.Key)"""
        if isinstance(profile, ndb.Model):
            profile = profile.key()  # Convert Model instances to a key

        return profile in self.profiles

class Profile(ndb.Model):
    # ...
```

As you can see, this also let's you quickly determine if a user has access to a given profile.

Answer (score 2):

`member = Member.query(Member.account==account).get()` means get the one instance.

`members = Member.query(Member.account==account).fetch()` returns the result in a list.

`memberQuery = Member.query(Member.account==account)` returns a Query class, that can be filtered again.